# What is the difference between the two models of Apple Pencil?

Tags: apple-pencil

I'm looking to buy an Apple Pencil for my iPad Pro 10.5". I find listings for two different model numbers: MK0C2AM/A and MK0C2ZM/A. Some listings, for example, on eBay have one model listed in the title and the other listed in the description.

What is the difference between the two models?

A friend told me that they had made a version update to fix certain lag issues, although I have used his Apple Pencil and have had no issues. Is this true? And if so, which model should I look for?

This very same question has been posted by others on the Apple support forum since April. None of them has an answer.

Comment: Whenever I found a description of the MK0C2ZM/A model, it said this: `Apple Pencil for iPad Pro, White (MK0C2ZM/A)`. The MK0C2AM/A specifies no color at all. Perhaps the Apple model number scheme is telling us that there will be pens in different colors planned? Who knows. I believe, _although have no definite proof_, that they are mechanically and operationally identical devices.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've never seen one that wasn't white. They're coming out with Apple Pencil 2, but I don't think that's till 2018. That might come in different colors. I'm not sure though.